# Neural net tensorboard debugger showing zeros for assign op

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

My neural net is not learning and so I spanned up Tensorboard Debugger to explore the potential problems. I have noticed that some optimizer assign ops are zeros. Is this normal?

For example:
[image]

Sorry for somewhat dry question, but perhaps someone stumbled across a problem like the above, and it has a common solution? Also what is interesting is that there is `Adam` and `Adam_1` as if there are two optimizers..